# MySQL column can't be found

Tags: mysql

Hi his query is giving me the following error:

Unknown column 'm.home_team_id' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
`m`.`match_id`), 
`m`.`competition_id`, 
`m`.`date`, 
`h`.`team_name` AS "homeTeam", `h`.`team_id` AS "homeTeamID", 
`a`.`team_name` AS "awayTeam", `a`.`team_id` AS "awayTeamID", 
`o`.`for`, `o`.`against` 
FROM `single` bs, `matches` m, `teams` t, `outcomes` o 
JOIN `teams` `h` ON `m`.`home_team_id`=`h`.`team_id` 
JOIN `teams` `a` ON `m`.`away_team_id`=`a`.`team_id` 
WHERE `bs`.`match_id`=`m`.`match_id` 
AND `m`.`score_id`=`o`.`outcome_id` 
AND `actual_return` IS NOT NULL`enter code here`
```

`m` is an alias of a table named matches which has columns `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` so I can't figure why the column can't be found?

Alan.

Comment: If you can't figure it out by watching the table schema, how are we supposed to do it without any schema ? add them to your question ...

Comment: the problem is how you're doing your joins.  @Lepidosteus - you can answer this question easily without schema.  `teams` is being joined (twice) to `outcomes o` but since `singles`, `matches` and `teams` are actually joined in the `where` and not by the `join` keyword (i dont know the technical term for the difference)... `teams` doesn't have access to `matches`

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit inner joins.  Get rid of the comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause and replace them all with explicit `JOIN`s.

Comment: you're mixing join styles. that's bad practice.plus you seem to be suffering from a serious case of backtickitis and incorrectusquotus

Comment: Are you sure that you have a column `home_team_id` in the `matches` table?

Comment: And I don't see where `teams t` is even joined with anything....?  (I might be reading it wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     DISTINCT (`m`.`match_id`), 
      `m`.`competition_id`, 
      `m`.`date`, 

      `h`.`team_name` AS "homeTeam",
      `h`.`team_id` AS "homeTeamID", 

      `a`.`team_name` AS "awayTeam",
      `a`.`team_id` AS "awayTeamID", 

      `o`.`for`, 
      `o`.`against` 

FROM `single` bs

      join `matches` m ON bs.match_id = m.match_id
      join `outcomes` o m.score_id = o.outcome_id 
      join `teams` t   --<--- I don't know what the join is for `teams` here 
                          --- you probably don't need this in the query at all 

      JOIN `teams` `h` ON `m`.`home_team_id`=`h`.`team_id` 
      JOIN `teams` `a` ON `m`.`away_team_id`=`a`.`team_id` 

WHERE  `actual_return` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 . . . I'll be the `distinct` isn't needed if you remove the `teams t` table from the join.

Comment: lol... you're probably right... `teams` is joined in there three times.  i can't imagine that is what OP actually wants/needs

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM a, b, c
JOIN d ON ...
JOIN e ON ...
```

Logically works like:

```
FROM a, b,
  (c
   JOIN d ON ...
   JOIN e ON ...)
```

Because the `JOIN` keyword has higher precedence than the comma.

So, for your example, when it tries to do that `JOIN`, it doesn't know what `m` is yet.

So you should be able to fix it by putting `matches` last, i.e. changing

```
FROM `single` bs, `matches` m, `teams` t, `outcomes` o
```

to:

```
FROM `single` bs, `teams` t, `outcomes` o, `matches` m
```

But, as Michael recommended, you shouldn't mix explicit join (using `JOIN`) and implicit join (using commas).

Also, `teams t` doesn't seem to be used at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mistake is on where to put the JOINS. If you want to JOIN the table `m`, you should put the JOIN next to it, instead of next to table `o`.

I think the way it is right now, the statement is trying to join table `o` with the table `h`. That's why it is not finding the table (and column) `m`.